# Does for(x = ...; x <= ...; x++) calculate ... in every loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

If I write

```
for (var x = Math.pow(2, 2); x <= Math.pow(2, 12.345); i++) doSomething();
```

Is that less efficient than writing

```
var a = Math.pow(2, 2);
var b = Math.pow(2, 12.345);
for (var x = a; x <= b; x++) doSomething();
```

?

Will the first example calculate for example Math.pow(2, 12.345) in every single loop, making it really slow?

Or are they both the same and equally fast?

Comment: That depends on compiler optimisation.

Comment: An example for consideration: Even declaring the length of an array in a separate variable has performance gains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first expression is the initial value(s), that's not recalculated.

Obviously the condition is evaluated each iteration, otherwise you wouldn't know when to finish.

Whether or not the condition expression *must* be recalculated depends on the expression and the JS implementation and its JIT etc.

Answer (score 2):

When an expression involves a function call, it's fairly unlikely that the optimizer will trust that the return value of the function is invariant and that the function has no side-effects.  So yes, it's probably the case that your test expression will be re-evaluated on every iteration. (Note that the initialization expression will just be done once, so there's not much point in moving it out of the loop header.)

Whether such hand-coded optimizations are worthwhile depends on the situation. If your loop goes through many, many iterations, then it may be worth it, but it might be wise to spend some time investigating an alternative that requires far fewer iterations.

Answer (score 0):

The condition checking is done for each iteration of the loop.

```
for (var x = Math.pow(2, 2); x <= Math.pow(2, 12.345); i++) doSomething();
```

So, `Math.pow(..` will be called each time for evaluating the condition. Because the execution of the loop depends on the condition. If the condition evaluates to `true` execution of the loop is continued, when the condition evaluates to `false` control is thrown outside/*break* of the loop.

Also, I don't see any need of evaluating the expression again and again in the loop condition as there involves no variable whose value is changed in loop.

Your code can be optimised as follow:

```
for (var x = Math.pow(2, 2), y = Math.pow(2, 12.345); x <= y; i++) doSomething();
```

Now, the static statement is moved in the *initialization* part, it will be evaluated only once when the loop execution starts.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Math.Pow will not be evaluated. See this:

```
>function z(){console.log("test"); return 3;}
<undefined

>z()
<3
<test

>var a = z();
<undefined
<test

>a
<3
```

You can test from any internet browser console. If the function was evaluated each time, `a` would have printed `test` which is not the case.

---

For the first case, it will be repeated each time:

```
>for (var x = 1; x <= z(); x++)console.log("itt");
<undefined
<test
<itt
<test
<itt
<test
<itt
<test
```

Comment: Oh, you were talking about the first one; you should be explicit, since there are two `Math.pow()` calls. At least I *assume* you're talking only about the first one.